# How to get array of hash arguments using Getopt::Long lib in perl?

Tags: perl, getopt-long

I want to take arguments as an array of hashes by using [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long) in my script. 
Consider the following command line example:

```
perl testing.pl --systems id=sys_1 ip_address=127.0.0.1 id=sys_2 ip_address=127.0.0.2
```

For the sake of simplicity, I'm using **two systems** and only **two sub arguments** of each system, i.e., `id` and `ip_address`. Ideally, the number of `systems` is dynamic; it may contain 1, 2 or more and so with the number of arguments of each system.

My script should handle these arguments in such a way that it will store in `@systems` array and each element will be a hash containing `id` and `ip_address`.

Is there any way in [Getopt::Long](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long) to achieve this without parsing it myself?

Following is pseudocode for what I'm trying to achieve:

---

**testing.pl**

```
use Getopt::Long;
my @systems;
GetOptions('systems=s' => \@systems);
foreach (@systems) {
  print $_->{id},' ', $_->{ip_address};
}
```

Comment: You mentioned in a comment you want multiple systems with multiple attributes. At this point, A JSON or YAML file sounds like the way to go.

Comment: @ikegami thanks for your input but with the current implementation of my framework I can't go with file approach. As I'm retrieving parameters from database and in a daemon I'm running `testing.pl` perl script using system command by passing arguments that I got from database.

Comment: Nothing in that prevents the use of a file/pipe.

Comment: Should the command line arg be quoted? `--systems "id=sys_1 ip_address=127.0.0.1 id=sys_2 ip_address=127.0.0.2"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an attempt, there might be more elegant solutions:

```
GetOptions('systems=s{1,}' => \my @temp );

my @systems;
while (@temp) {
    my $value1 = shift @temp;
    $value1 =~ s/^(\w+)=//; my $key1 = $1;
    my $value2 = shift @temp;
    $value2 =~ s/^(\w+)=//; my $key2 = $1;
    push @systems, { $key1 => $value1, $key2 => $value2 };
}

for (@systems) {
    print $_->{id},' ', $_->{ip_address}, "\n";
}
```

**Output**:

```
sys_1 127.0.0.1
sys_2 127.0.0.2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see with this approach I've to strictly follow the convention of passing the argument. Means if I pass `ip_address` first and then `id` it will fail. Can we enhance it in such a way that it'll work irrespective of position

Comment: It may contain more than two sub arguments. I've given only two for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: @Sadhu Ok, but how do you separate between sub arguments and system arguments? How do know which arguments belong to a given system?

Comment: yes it is also a problem. The command line that I gave is what I understood so far from getopt, it doesn't mean that I've to give command line options in that way. Basically at the end I want array of systems through getopts, irrespective of how we are giving command line options.
Hope I didn't confuse you more. Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: Have a look at the suggestion in the answer by @SimonShine. He suggest to add a new `--system` flag between each system argument group. In this way you can separate which sub arguments belong to each system

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168292/discussion-between-sadhu-and-hakon-haegland).

Comment: thank you so much sir it's working. Thank you for devoting your precious time for me. I can't use chat because of less reputation, that's why I'm commenting here.

Comment: @Sadhu You are welcome! Feel free to contact me by email if you want to discuss other coding issues. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

I actually think this is a design problem, more than a problem with `GetOpt` - the notion of supporting multiple, paired arguments passed as command line arguments I think is something that you'd be far better off avoiding.

There's a reason that `GetOpt` doesn't really support it - it's not a scalable solution really.

How about instead just reading the values from `STDIN`?:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %systems = do { local $/; <DATA> } =~ m/id=(\w+) ip_address=([\d\.]+)/mg;

print Dumper \%systems;
```

And then you'd be able to invoke your script as:

```
perl testing.pl <filename_with_args>
```

Or similar.

And if you *really* must:

```
my %systems = "@ARGV" =~ m/id=(\w+) ip_address=([\d\.]+)/g;
```

Both of the above work for multiple parameters.

However, your comment on another post:

> I can't because I'm fetching parameters from database and converting them into command line and then passing it to the script using system command `$cmd_lines_args = '--system --id sys_1 --ip_address 127.0.0.0.1'; system("perl testing.pl $cmd_lines_args");` $cmd_lines_args I'll generate dynamically using for loop by reading from database

.. that makes this an XY Problem.

Don't do it like that:

```
open ( my $script, '|-', "perl testing.pl" );
print {$script} "id=some_id ip_address=10.9.8.7\n";
print {$script} "id=sys2 ip_address=10.9.8.7\n";
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As  I mentioned I can't go with the file and also it is not only two arguments `id` and `ip_address`, it can be more.

Comment: `echo "id=1 ip_address=1.1.1.1" | perl testing.pl` will do the trick. Both of the above handle multiple instances of id/system pairs.

Comment: Also - building args and then embedding them in a `system` call is an awful approach to IPC.

Comment: @Sadhu: You haven't given a good reason why you can't use a file for input. **Sobrique** is correct: this is a misuse of command-line arguments.

Comment: @Sobrique your solution is not working for me in many situations.
**1.** It is position constraint, It will break if I use `ip_address` first and then `id`.
**2.** If I give one more parameter for example `conn_type=ssh` and change the code accordingly it gives me 
`{
    'ssh' => undef,
     'sys_1' => '192.168.0.1'
  };`
**3.** You are seeing only the half picture. I've written `--systems` as main command and then defining sub arguments inside it because it will contain other arguments also, contd...

Comment: ... for example `perl testing.pl --fio rw=write direct=0 --systems id=sys_1 ip_address=1.1.1.1 --systems id=sys_2 ip_address=1.1.1.1`.

Comment: If you're saying that you can't use a file or a pipe for the input because you haven't designed it that way, then your design needs changing. Seriously, don't go with this just because it's the first thing that came into your head. We've been trying to tell you that it's a ***bad approach*** for several reasons.

Comment: If your problem is more complicated, then the way you get useful answers is to include that information in your question. There are other ways to deal with multiple/positional input. I've just offered the simplest way of handling what you've said you're trying to do. But if it's more complicated than that, I'd suggest your IPC is best done via passing JSON into your script.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing,

> ```
> --systems id=sys_1 ip_address=127.0.0.1 id=sys_2 ip_address=127.0.0.2
> ```

appears to be one option that takes a variable number of arguments that are pairs, and come in multiples of two. [`Getopt::Long`'s "Options with multiple values"](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Options-with-multiple-values) lets you do the following:

```
GetOptions('systems=s{2,4}' => \@systems);
```

This lets you specify 2, 3 or 4 arguments, but it does not have syntax for "any even number of arguments" (to cover an arbitrary number of pairs beyond two), and you still have to unpack the `id=sys_1` manually then. You can write a [user-defined subroutine](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#User-defined-subroutines-to-handle-options) that handles the processing of `--systems`' arguments (but does not take into account missing `id=...`s):

```
my $system;
my %systems;

GetOptions('systems=s{,}' => sub {
    my $option = shift;
    my $pair = shift;
    my ($key, $value) = split /=/, $pair;

    $system = $value if $key eq 'id';
    $systems{$system} = $value if $key eq 'ip_address';
});
```

I would however prefer one of the following schemes:

```
--system sys_1 127.0.0.1 --system sys_2 127.0.0.1
--system sys_1=127.0.0.1 --system sys_2=127.0.0.1
```

They're achieved with the following:

```
GetOptions('system=s{2}', \@systems);
GetOptions('system=s%', \@systems);
```

Comment: Excuse me for not writing down the problem statement properly. Actually just for the sake of simplicity I've given example with two sub arguments. Ideally it contains more than two and I'm bit skeptical that it will work when argument is more than two

Comment: And also it may contain more than two systems.

Comment: Why are you passing longer lists of things via flags on command line? Would it not be way easier to feed them in via STDIN?

Comment: @Sobrique, I can't because I'm fetching parameters from database and converting them into command line and then passing it to the script using system command

`$cmd_lines_args = '--system --id sys_1 --ip_address 127.0.0.0.1';
system("perl testing.pl $cmd_lines_args");`

`$cmd_lines_args` I'll generate dynamically using for loop by reading from database.

Comment: @Sadhu: All three suggestions work for more `--system`s than two. You could easily have tried this instead of being passively skeptical. The fact that your data comes from a database has nothing to do with what input scheme you use (stdin, or any of the suggested parameter schemes). Consider using [`IPC::System::Simple::systemx()`](http://search.cpan.org/~pjf/IPC-System-Simple-1.25/lib/IPC/System/Simple.pm#runx(),_systemx()_and_capturex()) instead of `system()`.

Comment: OK. So `system("perl testing.pl...` makes this a classic XY problem. Don't use `system` and this problem goes away. Open it as a file handle:

Comment: @SimonShine I think you misunderstood my first comment. I said more than two sub arguments of a system viz,. `--systems id=sys_1 ip_address=1.1.1.1 conn_type=ssh os_type=ubuntu` etc..

Answer (score 0):

I would just parse the `--systems` arg and quote the "hashes" like this:

```
perl testing.pl --systems "id=s1 ip_address=127.0.0.1 id=s2 ip_address=127.0.0.2"
```

Parse like perhaps so:

```
my($systems,@systems);
GetOptions('systems=s' => \$systems);
for(split/\s+/,$systems){
    my($key,$val)=split/=/,$_,2;
    push @systems, {} if !@systems or exists$systems[-1]{$key};
    $systems[-1]{$key}=$val;
}
print "$_->{id} $_->{ip_address}\n" for @systems;
```

Prints:

```
sys_1 127.0.0.1
sys_2 127.0.0.2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  How `print` statement will work?

Comment: (upvote is the best kind of thanks here - click that up arrow;-) Not sure if I understand *«How `print` statement will work»*) If you run my code you will see how. And you have the same `print` in your original query, except you used a `foreach` loop and I used a `for` statement modifier. In this case those are synonymous.